# La plej bona traduko de la angla "Let's play it by ear"?

Tags: translation, phrase-requests, idiom

Ĉu "Ni ludu ĝin per orelo" havas la saman signifon kiel la angla, ke ni ne planas, anstataŭ decidos dum la afero kion fari?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mi suspektas ke tiu senco de *play by ear* estas angla idiomaĵo kaj do oni povas traduki *let's play it by ear* per *ni faru tion senprepare/improvize*.

Se temas pri muzika senco de la vorto (to play an instrument by ear) la libro *Cent jaroj da soleco* uzas *ludi laŭaŭde*:

> *One Hundred Years of Solitude*: [...] learning to play the accordion **by ear** [...]
>
> *Cent jaroj da soleco*: [...] lernante ludi **laŭaŭde** la akordionon [...]